# How to access a member using a variable with Flux

Tags: influxdb, flux-influxdb

According to the [docs](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud/reference/flux/language/expressions/), you can use square brackets for member access. However, when I try to do this using a variable it results in the errors below.

```
a = "ABC"
b = "DEF"

//This works
calc = (r) => r.ABC - r.DEF

calc = (r) => r["ABC"] - r["DEF"]

//However, I can't find a way to access the members using the variables

calc = (r) => r["${a}"] - (r["${b}"]
> type error @8:23-8:36: expected int but found string


calc = (r) => r[a] - r[b]
> type error @8:23-8:31: expected int but found string
```

How do you access members using a variable?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry - the same docs I referenced had the answer:

> It is not possible to access a record’s property using an arbitrary expression.